# bash; removing any of a set of suffixes

Tags: bash, pattern-matching

Bash scripting on OSX Snow Leopard, I want to remove any of a set of file suffixes and my googlefu is failing me.

Given

```
file="filename_1"
file1=${file%_1}
echo $file1
filename
```

However, any variations of introducing a pattern list into the stripping have failed me, e.g.:

```
shopt -s extglob
file1=${file/@(%_1|%_end)/}
echo $file1
filename_1
```

I've tried putting the pattern list in a variable, using parenthesis or none, quotes or none. 
I'm coming to conclude that substitutions and trimming of trailing strings don't take pattern lists - or that I'm missing something rather obvious. Thank you for suggestions on elegant solutions or on what I might be missing about pattern lists.

Answer (score 4):

You just have the syntax a bit wrong: `${file%@(_1|_end)}`

```
$ printf "%s\n" filename_1 filename_2 filename_end | 
  while read file; do echo ${file%@(_1|_end)}; done
filename
filename_2
filename
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Answer (score 0):

If it's acceptable to use two commands, you can do something like this with `sed`:

```
echo $YOURVARIABLE | sed 's/\(_1\|_WHAT\|_EVER\|_EXTENSION\)$//'
```